# Viewing photo attachments in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, attachments, photos

I usually use ArcMap to display photo attachments in a point layer. If I click the point with the HTML Popup tool, it displays a small photo corresponding to the point and I can click on it to open it in an external view where I can zoom in and out.

I can't find the equivalent in ArcGIS Pro. I can see the attachment using the Explore tool (in the Map tab), but then I can't open it like in ArcMap. I am stuck with the picture the size of a thumbnail.

How do I open the attached photo in an external viewer from the popup windows in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 3):

Under the editing tab, select attributes, then in the side panel choose attachments. From there you can open or save photo attachments.

Answer (score 0):

The only options I'm seeing in ArcGIS Pro is adding a hyperlink or URL to the image. I would use this and store the image in that link. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/configure-pop-ups.htm

Comment: This works as long as there is only one link in the field that contains the url.

Answer (score 0):

For layers with enabled attachments, you can display a list of attachments in a pop-up by enabling the **Show list of Attachments** option in the **Configure Pop-ups pane** (check box at the bottom). When a feature includes attachments and this option is enabled, a list of hyperlinks is displayed, ordered from oldest to newest, at the bottom of the pop-up. These links open the attachment in the default file handler.

Link: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/navigation/pop-ups.htm